# OpenGL Mutlisampling Multiple Render Target FBO's

Tags: opengl, multisampling

I am trying Deferred Shading and I am having troubles trying to MultiSample a Multiple Render Target.    It Seems as if I am only copying over one anti-Aliased Texture instead of 3 (Diffuse,Position,Normals). Only the Diffuse are copied.

This is the Anti Alias FBO creation for my Geometry Pass:

```
IntBuffer drawBuffs = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(3);
private void CreateFBOAntiAlias() {

    AntiAliasFrameBuffer = glGenFramebuffers();
    GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, AntiAliasFrameBuffer);

    textureColorMultiSampled = generateMultiSampleTexture(4);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
    GL32.GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, textureColorMultiSampled,
    0);

    texturePositionMultiSampled = generateMultiSampleTexture(4);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1,
    GL32.GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, texturePositionMultiSampled ,
    0);

    textureNormalMultiSampled = generateMultiSampleTexture(4);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2,
    GL32.GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, textureNormalMultiSampled ,
    0);


    drawBuffs.put(0, GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
    drawBuffs.put(1, GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
    drawBuffs.put(2, GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2);


    GL20.glDrawBuffers(drawBuffs);

    AntiAliasRenderBufferObject = glGenRenderbuffers();

    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, AntiAliasRenderBufferObject);
    glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 4,
            GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, width, height);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT,
            GL_RENDERBUFFER, AntiAliasRenderBufferObject);

    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        System.err
                .println("ERROR::FRAMEBUFFER:: Framebuffer is not complete!");
    } else {
        System.err.println("FrameBuffer AntiAliasFBO success");
    }
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}

 private int generateMultiSampleTexture(int samples) {
    int texture;
    texture = GL11.glGenTextures();

    GL11.glBindTexture(GL32.GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, texture);
    GL32.glTexImage2DMultisample(GL32.GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, samples,
            GL11.GL_RGBA8, width, height, true);
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL32.GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 0);

    return texture;

}
```

This is the creation for my Target FBO:

```
public void CreateFBO() {

    fbo_handle = glGenFramebuffers();
    diffuse_handle = GL11.glGenTextures();
    position_handle = GL11.glGenTextures();
    normal_handle = GL11.glGenTextures();
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo_handle);

    //////////////////DIFFUSE////////////////////////////////////
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, diffuse_handle);
    GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, width, height,0, 
            GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_INT, (ByteBuffer) null);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
            GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, diffuse_handle, 0);

    /////////////////POSITION////////////////////////////////////
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, position_handle);
    GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, width, height, 0,
            GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_INT, (ByteBuffer) null);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1,
            GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, position_handle, 0);

    ///////////////NORMALS/////////////////////////////////////////
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, normal_handle);
    GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F, width, height, 0,
            GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_INT, (ByteBuffer) null);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2,
            GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, normal_handle, 0);
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    drawBuffs.put(0, GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
    drawBuffs.put(1, GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
    drawBuffs.put(2, GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2);

    GL20.glDrawBuffers(drawBuffs);

    rbo_depth_buffer_handle = glGenRenderbuffers();
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo_depth_buffer_handle);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL14.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32,
            width, height);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,
            GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo_depth_buffer_handle);

    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        System.err.println("Framebuffer configuration error");
    } else {

        System.err.println("Deferred configuration Success");
    }

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}
```

I bind my AA FBO during the Geometry pass, unbind it and perform a Blit from the AA FBO to my Target FBO and Render the Fullscreen Quad with undesire results.

```
public void blit() {
    GL11.glEnable(GL13.GL_MULTISAMPLE);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, AntiAliasFrameBuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo_handle);
    glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height,
            GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

}
```

Edit: I've tried blitting from a normal MRT fbo to another normal MRT FBO without the Multi-Sampling calls and again it seems i'm copying over just ONE texture.  Rhe root of my problem is incorrectly blitting an MRT to another MRT.

Comment: I tried that before the drawbuffs call  and gave me an exception :/   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
at java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:532)
at java.nio.DirectIntBufferU.put(DirectIntBufferU.java:300)

Comment: Oops, sorry. I didn't notice that you already allocated `drawBuffs` with a size ahead of time. I thought you were calling `put` to increase the size each time.

Comment: Looks like  a typo: You are attaching `textureColorMultiSampled` 3 times.

Comment: Ah ty, I fixed that typo  and updated my question.  It seems to be copying over just one texture still.  I know something is wrong with my blitting I just don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

Whew, ok My main problem was my blitting was incorrect.  The blitting Method should be

```
public void blit() {

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, AntiAliasFrameBuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo_handle);



    GL11.glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
    GL11.glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);

    glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height,
            GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL11.GL_NEAREST);


    GL11.glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
    GL11.glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
    glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height,
            GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL11.GL_NEAREST);



    GL11.glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2);
    GL11.glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2);

    glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height,
            GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL11.GL_NEAREST);


    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

}
```

the general setup for my AA FBO/FBO is correct, and all textures are copied over successfully and with major improvement over Aliasing.